# Dynamic 2D array - allocation won't work (segfault)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, dynamic-allocation

Why wouldn't this work? I've reviewed my code several times and just can't find what's wrong.

Thanks!

```
void generateData(float** inData, int x, int y){
    inData[0][0]= 3000.0; // SEGFAULT
}

float** createMatrix(int x, int y){
    float** array= malloc(sizeof(float*) * y);
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float** arr = createMatrix(100,2);

    generateData(arr, 100, 2);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I dont see a return of array from your createMatrix routine! In other words, arr never gets the actual pointer to your 2D array.

Comment: Compiling with `-wall` will help you quite a bit sometimes :)

Comment: Note that you can simply use `float * array = malloc(sizeof(float)*w*h)` and then access the members via `array[x+y*w]`.

Comment: Can't see how I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot this ever so important line;

```
return array;
```

in `createMatrix`.  Look at your compiler warnings, or turn them on if you don't already have them on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this snippet directly relates to your code, but you never returned the address from createMatrix().

Answer (score 0):

`return array;` is one problem in you code. Apart from that one more big problem is there.

`float** array= malloc(sizeof(float*) * y);` - You are first allocating memory for array to store array of pointers(to float). And then you are allocating memory for each row `malloc(sizeof(float) * x);`

Now you have allocated memory for 2 rows and 100 columns.Then Call `generateData(arr, 100, 2);`. In `generateData` if you do like `inData[100][2]` this will leads to crash. Because you have allocated only 2 rows and each rows has 100 elements. `inData[100][2]` is equivalent to `*( *(inData + 100) + 2)`. Here `*(inData + 100)` will leads to crash(undefined behaviour). Because you are suppose to access only upto index `1` not `100`.

Mistake is in `createMatrix` function, you have wrongly used the `x` and `y`. Rewrite your function like below.

```
float** createMatrix(int x, int y)
{
    int i;
    float** array= (float **)malloc(sizeof(float*) * x);
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * y);
    }
    return array;
}
```

And also rewrite your `generateData` also as below.

```
void generateData(float** inData, int x, int y)
{
    x--;
    y--;    
    inData[i][j]= 3000.0; //Do you assignment to array here
}
```